# Outdoor Webcam for low temperatures and fog

Tags: home-security, webcam

I want to install an outdoor surveillance camera. I looked into many models, but all have rather strange, i.e., non-outdoor, operating conditions they are specified for.

Typically they have a temperature range of -20°C to 50°C (-4°C to 122°F). The upper-bound of all models i looked at is more than fine for central Europe, but the lower bound is not. Temperatures below -20°C are quite common where I live. Some cameras go down to -30°C (e.g., the UniFi Models). This is okay, but leaves only a small margin of error.

The next strange thing is the "operating humidity". Virtually all models I have found have something like 20 - 90% noncondensing. Even the water-proofed ones!?? We have fog over here. I do not live in England, but fog is still common here.

Any recommendations what to use?
Concerning the other specs, I do not need much. A resolution of 1280x720 (or more) is fine. Night vision is nice, but not necessary. WiFi would be great, but I could also run a cable (since it already needs to be powered somehow). PoE is also optional.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that even the cameras rated for outside will corrode.  I found this out when 3 of my cameras suddenly got stuck on night vision.  It appears that this a mechanical thing and has corroded in  place.